# jQuery nextUntil strangeness

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Am I missing something or is this method fubar? I couldn't get a script to select properly, so I stripped everything out except jQuery 1.5 and tried this as a test:

HTML:

```
  <a href="test.php" id="test" class="notActive">test active</a>
  <p><a href="ui.php#content" class="ajax" data-target="loadid">Link 1</a></p>
  <p><a href="widgets.html" class="ajax" data-target="loadid">Link 2</a></p>
  <div id="loadid" class="right bgGreen pad">test;</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var z = $('#test').nextUntil('div');

z.css({'background-color' : '#000000' });

console.log(z.html());
```

Returns:

```
<a href="test.php" id="test" class="notActive">test active</a>
<p style="background-color: #000000">
<a href="ui.php#content" class="ajax" data-target="loadid">
</p>
<p style="background-color: #000000">
<a href="widgets.html" class="ajax" data-target="loadid">
</p>
<div id="loadid" class="right bgGreen pad">


LOG: <\a href="ui.php#content" class="ajax" data-target="loadid">Link 1</a>
```

Also, changing the selector from 'div' to 'p' results null... any ideas?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to select?

Comment: [It works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/SLaks/PB5wp/).

Comment: I was going after #loadid... julkiewicz explained the issue: nextUntil selects all elements until the named selector. I still don't understand why dragonfly & firebug were only logging the 1st <a> though...

Comment: @user: my answer explains why only the first `<a>` gets logged.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing something. From [the jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil):

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the `.nextUntil()`method allows us to search through the successors of these elements in the DOM tree, stopping when it reaches an element matched by the method's argument. The new jQuery object that is returned contains all following siblings up to but not including the one matched by the `.nextUntil()` selector.

The value returned by your `nextUntil()` contains **multiple elements**, namely the two `<p>`s . Logging the value returned by `.html()`is misleading because [`.html()` returns only the **inner** HTML of the **first** object in the set](http://api.jquery.com/html#html2). Just log the jQuery object itself and you should be able to see what's inside it (at least in Firebug; I don't think WebKit's debugger logs jQuery objects as nicely):

```
console.log(z);
```

Which element are you trying to select?

Comment: Thanks- I got it! To select the #loadid, is there a cleaner method than .nextUntil('e').next()?

Comment: @user: why don't you just select the `#loadid` directly? `$('#loadid')` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Well this seems right. According to http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/ the .nextUntil selects all the siblings until but *not including* the element selected by the argument. So if you do .nextUntil('div') you select all the paragraphs (which are siblings to your #test element). If you do .nextUntil('p') nothing gets selected, because a paragraph apprears right after the #test.

Answer (score -2):

Your .css syntax is wrong I think.

Should have a "," instead of ":"

```
z.css('background-color', '#000000' );
```

Comment: The OP has passed in a javascript object (I think that's the correct terminology), so the syntax is correct.

Comment: @Matt: yes, it's called a JS object.